# Silverstripe calendar picker to not show past dates

Tags: datepicker, calendar, silverstripe

Is there a way to set the calendar picker in Silverstripe to not be able to select dates that are in the past?

As far as I can tell it uses the jQuery DatePicker but I am unsure how to restrict the past dates.

```
DateField::create("Date","Date")
            ->setAttribute('placeholder','eg 2017-01-01')
            ->setConfig('showcalendar', true),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass configuration options to the datepicker:

```
DateField::create("Date","Date")
    ->setConfig('showcalendar', true)
    ->setConfig('min', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->setDescription('')
    ->setAttribute('data-number-of-months', 3);
```

`->setConfig('min', date('Y-m-d'))` tells jQueryUI picker to use a minimal date (today). With data-attributes you can also pass other configuraton to the picker, in the above case it shows three months at once. This will be passed to datepicker config.

Note that the datepicker camel case config "numberOfMonths" has to be written with hyphens like 'data-number-of-months'.

See also [datepicker configuration](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is perfect.

Comment: Had a hard time with it some weeks ago. I have two pickers that should set min/max date for each other (arrival and departure). This doesn't replace backend validation but is a bit more userfriendly.